# Transform referral-traffic into organic with Organic Search Sources

Tags: google-analytics

Few years ago Yandex (Search System) following Google removed any search-phrase information from referer (only origin is known – `https://yandex.…/`), and now Yandex-traffic mostly becomes "referral" in GA.

To solve this problem i've added a [new organic search source in property tracking settings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821#ChangeOrganicSearchSettings) (we using `analytics.js`-script of Universal Analytics):

- Search Engine Name: `yandex`
- Domain Name Contains: `yandex.ru`
- Query Parameter and Path Contains left blank.

[image]

So, a properly added custom organic source must have a higher priority than referral (as described on [Processing flow chart](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762)) and matched traffic must becomes "organic".

But it didn't work, and Yandex search traffic still marked as "yandex.ru / referral" instead of "yandex.ru / organic".

[image]

I've tryed different combinations of the "Domain Name Contains" pattern:

- `^yandex\.` (regexp style)
- `yandex.`
- `yandex.ru`
  with no effect.

By default there are [built-in Yandex source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821#searchEngine), but it catch only traffic with referrer and "text"-parameter – only organic traffic.
But Yandex doesn't send path and parameters in the referer anymore, as i told above.

And two built-in hosts – http://www.yandex.com/ and http://yandex.ru – is not enough: Yandex has a many TLDs: yandex.ru, yandex.ua, yandex.kz and many more – one for every country where it works.

So, built-in organic sources for Yandex are obsolete.
What's why i'am trying to use a custom organic search.

Questions are:

1. Why no one of the variants (`yandex.` and `yandex.ru`) is not
   worked for Yandex's traffic and i'am still see same "yandex.ru /
   referral" share?
2. Can regular expression patterns (`^yandex\.`, for
   `https://yandex.ru`) be used in the "Domain Name Contains" field of the organic search source?
3. Which value for "Domain Name Contains" field should i use for
   catching `https://yandex.ru/` referer (without any path and parameters in referer URL) as an organic search source?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, it is advisable to create **2 custom filters**:

- Advanced
- Search and replace

The **Advanced** filter will be used to transform the medium from referral to organic.

Requires to enter the following Campaign Source as **Field A**:

```
^yandex\.(ru|ua|by|kz|uz|com|fr|com\.tr)$
```

In **Field B** (to be set as mandatory) select the `Campaign medium`, which must contain the term referral and in the Output field, the campaign medium, this time however must contain the term `organic`.

The **Search and Replace** filter will then have the function of transforming all the various domains (yandex.ru, yandex.by, yandex.kz, yandex.ua, etc...) into the generic yandex.
It prompts you to select the `Campaign Source` as the filter field, then the following string as the field to search for:

```
^yandex\.(ru|ua|by|kz|uz|com|fr|com\.tr)$
```

And the term `yandex` as a string to replace.

This will make it possible to obtain all the traffic in question as `yandex / organic` on the platform. Consequently, the acquired data will end up in the desired channel and the session metrics will allow performing analyzes, as they will be aggregated.

https://www.analyticstraps.com/yandex-e-visto-come-referral-anziche-organico/

Comment: I know "two filters" solution, but this is crutch. 
 
This "solution" relabel invalid labeled traffic, instead of fix the root cause of mislabeling. 
And it requires a filter for every view in property.

Comment: Event though in German this blog post provides a better solution via custom task: https://www.markus-baersch.de/blog/organische-besucher-im-griff-eine-abkuerzung-fuer-google-analytics/